# "3rd party apps designed to use mobile data" even when connected to WiFi

Tags: applications, wi-fi, mobile-data, huawei

I found something curious researching this topic:

> #### 3rd party apps designed to use mobile data
>
> Some third-party apps, such as online banking apps, may still consume mobile data even when they are connected to a wireless network. This issue occurs on all Android phones and cannot be resolved by changing the settings on your phone.
>
> Such apps usually do not consume much mobile data. If you are worried about data consumption, **swipe down from the status bar** to open the notification panel and tap the **Mobile data icon** to disable mobile data.

Source: Huawei (https://consumer.huawei.com/uk/support/content/en-gb00459970/)

I noticed this in the past, some specific apps seem to trigger the '4G' icon for brief seconds while connected to wifi, opening chrome and checking my IP always returns my WiFi IP while the icon is on, also I don't see any flaky WiFi connection.

Why is that? Is it something about location accuracy?

Comment: Welcome to Android Enthusiasts, a Q&A site for Android end-users solving their issues. Note that the 3rd question about programming question is off-topic here (and have been removed) and might be more suitable on [so].