# Some app, whose mobile access is restricted, suddenly starts using data after switching mobile carrier

Tags: mobile-data, huawei

My problem is some apps I specifically disallow data access started to use mobile data after I switched mobile company. I didn't change any settings. It never happened with two previous carriers with the same phone.
I don’t know if my smartphone is malfunctioning, a malware is installed, or something else?
Here is what happened:

1. I use prepaid mobile plan with minimum data, so I always disable mobile data for most apps (set individually in the App section in the Settings). It worked fine for years.
2. On Nov 24th, I switched a mobile company (from Lucky mobile (Bell) to Chatr wireless (Rogers), both Canadian carriers) and swapped SIM cards. It took about 24 hours before I could use data.
3. While I still didn't know if the data was available, I used Google Map and Google Chrome, both are set to wifi only. They worked but I thought I was in a wifi hotspot that is everywhere in a city. Then I played a game I specifically disallow BOTH wifi and mobile data (so that I can play it locally without seeing any ad).  At the end of the game I saw an ad, it was the time I realized my data was finally available and the data was consumed. But why, the app is prohibited to use any data including wifi and mobile data.
4. I checked the Settings. The settings remain the same but the Google map and Chrome along with the game app consumed data. I restarted the phone but it didn’t make a difference.

I was afraid that my phone was hacked, so I installed Norton 360 and scanned a malware but nothing was detected.
I installed NetGuard so that I can control data access easily. For now I disable mobile data of the phone all together and manually enable it when I use data then disable it when I finish. It works for now but I am still puzzled.

Current situation:
When I open an app with restricted data, for most apps, I get this message: “** was restricted from using your cellular network. Remove the restriction?” which is normal and supposed to be like that.

However, there is an app, specifically Google Chrome, accesses mobile data without showing the message. Strangely Google Map and the game app that used data on the first day, now show the above message.
I understand that small data is still transmitted while mobile data is disallowed, but this is not the case.

My phone is 3-years old Huawei Nova 3, Android version 9, and I don’t have any problem with the phone except for a shorter battery life.

My biggest fear is that my phone is compromised as it happens when I swapped SIM cards. If my phone is just too old and malfunctioning, I can get a new phone. Any help will be appreciated. Thanks.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Possibly related/dupe (but not answered yet): ["3rd party apps designed to use mobile data" even when connected to WiFi](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/248962/44325)

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I am aware that some apps transmit small piece of data background but I don't feel like it is the case.... Google Chrome is set to wifi only, so if I try to open it without wifi, it's supposed to show the message "Google Chrome was restricted from using your cellular network. Remove the restriction?", however. it automatically connects to the mobile network without asking me anything.